# Reversar el orden de iteración de las propiedades de un objeto

Tags: javascript, object

Tengo un objeto como el sig:

```
obj = {
 2015 : [01,02,03],
 2016 : [01,02,03,04],
 2017 : [01,02,03]
}
```

Quiero "reversear" ese objeto a:

```
obj = {
 2017 : [01,02,03],
 2016 : [01,02,03,04],
 2015 : [01,02,03]
}
```

Puesto que al iterarlo accedo primero a la propiedad "2015", asumo entonces que el orden de iteración es el mismo al de la declaración de los objetos

Necesito encontrar una forma de cambiar el orden de iteración de ese objeto. Por ejemplo, si fuera un array simplemente agregaría `reverse`, pero no puedo hacer lo mismo en la iteración de este objeto, por cuestiones de uso yo necesito cambiar dicho orden de iteración (que el último se convierta en el primero).

***Actualizado***

Tengo este código, ya logré iterar el objeto de otra forma:

```
years = {
  2015 : [11,12],
  2016 : [01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10],
  2017 : [01,02,03,04,05,06]
}

function reverseForIn(obj, f) {
  var arr = [];
  var key;
  var i;
  for (key in years) {
    // add hasOwnPropertyCheck if needed
    arr.push(key);
      console.log(arr)
      console.log(key)
  }
  for (i=arr.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    f.call(years, arr[i]);
  }
}

//uso
reverseForIn(years, function(key){ console.log('KEY:', key, 'VALUE:', this[key]); });
```

En la parte final tengo un problema, pues me lo da como quiero pero lo quiero guardar de nuevo en years (volver a llenar mi objeto pero ya acomodado).

¿Se puede lograr esto?

Comment: Eddy, así como te comentabamos ayer, será mejor si pones un [ejemplo minimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). De esa forma podremos ayudarte mejor y obtendras una buena respuesta. Es decir, ¿que has intentado? ¿tienes algun error?

Comment: Gracias, ¿crees que así se mejore?

Comment: Eddy, las propiedades de un objeto no estan ordenadas. No hay nada que reversar. Si te refieres al la impresion del objeto, por favor aclaralo

Comment: Como te comentan, el orden en que se muestra es el orden en que ingresaron, pero tu puedes manipularlo y darle el orden que quieras o necesites.

Comment: ¿Pero como puedo reordenalos?

Comment: @Eddy, el objeto lo armas tu con ese formato?

Comment: Amplia un poco mas el contexto de tu problema para poder encontrar una solicion ¿El objeto tu lo generas o lo obtienes de algun lado?¿Es posible que en lugar de un objeto sea un arreglo de objetos?¿cúal es el proposito de ordenarlos?

Comment: No se pueden reordenar las propiedades, en firefox te muestra las propiedades de menor a mayor no importa como las metas

Comment: explica el caso de uso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código casi hace lo que quieres.

Te falta tener en cuenta que los elementos de un objeto carecen de garantía de orden. Y por tanto tampoco existe un orden invertido.
Aunque en tu código los has añadido en el orden 2015, 2016 y 2017 es posible que al ejecutar e iterar ese objeto te salgan en cualquier otro orden.

Lo que puedes hacer es convertir el objeto a array. Los arrays si tienen un orden. De hecho eso ya lo haces bien, en el siguiente código tuyo :

```
var arr = [];
var key;
var i;
for (key in years) {
  // add hasOwnPropertyCheck if needed
  arr.push(key);
  console.log(arr)
  console.log(key)
}
```

Aunque para que el array tenga las propiedades y no solo las claves la línea del push debiera ser así:

```
arr.push( [key, years[key]] )
```

Y después puedes invertir el orden usando también tu código :

```
for (i=arr.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
```

Falta solo usar ese segundo bucle para insertar en orden contrario. Sería así:

```
invertido = [];
for (i=arr.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
  invertido.push( arr[i] )
}
```

Todo lo anterior reorganizado en funciones independientes queda así:

```js
years = {
  2015 : [11,12],
  2016 : [01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10],
  2017 : [01,02,03,04,05,06]
}

// Devuelve un objeto convertido en array
function objAarray( obj ) {
  resultado = []
  for ( key in obj) {
    resultado.push( [key, obj[key]])
  }
  return resultado
}

// El parámetro de entrada debe ser un array
// Devuelve el array invertido
function reverse( obj ) {
  var resultado = [];
  for (i=obj.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    resultado.push(obj[i])
  }
  return resultado
}

console.log( 'Objeto:' , years )
years = objAarray(years)
console.log( 'Array:', years )
years = reverse(years)
console.log( 'Array reverseado:', years )
```

Comment: pregunta: he seguido al pie de la letra tus pasos y tus comentarios, y mi pregunta es, no puedo volver hacerlo objeto, lo detallo simple:                         objeto -> array -> arrayReverse -> objetoDeNuevo....

Comment: ¿Puedo volver objeto el array que ya tengo reversado?,no comprendo bien el algoritmo en el que estoy trabajando, pero por una extraña razón no me funciona si lo convierto en array mi objeto dates.

Comment: @Eddy Sí se puede volver a convertir el array en objeto. Pero si lo haces no tendrás un objeto reverseado puesto que los objetos no tienen orden. Aunque es posible que en la mayoría de implementaciones sí se comporte como si fuese un objeto reverseado que respeta ese orden. En cualquier caso esto es material para otra pregunta. Que puedes hacer en este mismo sitio si quieres: ¿Como convertir un array de pares [clave,valor] en un objeto?

Answer (score 5):

#### Marco teórico

Los miembros de un objeto como tal, no tienen orden alguno, así los objetos `{foo: "foo",bar: "bar"}` y `{bar: "bar", "foo": "foo"}` son completamente iguales.

Recordad que un objeto es un arreglo asociativo, un mapeo sobre un conjunto *X* a un conjunto *Y*, en javascript el conjunto *X* son cadenas de texto, y el conjunto *Y* cualquier tipo válido (cadenas de texto, valores booleanos, numeros y obj).

#### Pseudo Orden

Dadas las implementaciones adyacentes a los objetos, existe un pseudo orden en las propiedades, en javascript este falso orden se da por la tabla de descriptores del objeto, dicha tabla al recorrerse da como origen un *orden* indefinido, totalmente dependiente a la implementación del interpréte o compilador *JIT*

Ejemplo:

```js
var objA = {foo: "foo", bar: "bar"}
var objB = {bar: "bar", foo: "foo"}
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(objA))  
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(objB)) // distinto a objA
```

El hacer `for..in` en un objeto, recorre la tabla de descriptores, así que puede parecer que los elementos *esten ordenados* cuando es falso, ya que los miembros podrían aparecer en cualquier permutación posible.

```js
var objA = {foo: "foo", bar: "bar"}

for (let propiedad in objA)
  {
    console.log(objA[propiedad])
  }
```

```js
var objB = {bar: "bar", foo: "foo"}

for (let propiedad in objB)
  {
    console.log(objB[propiedad])
  }
```

### Revertir el orden en la tabla de descriptores

La mayoría de implementaciones de javascript utilizan una estructura tipo FIFO para los descriptores de los objetos es decir que el orden es el mismo conforme se definan.

```js
function reversir_descriptores(){
 var dscrpts = {}

 var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).reverse()

 for(let prop of props)
   {
    dscrpts[prop] = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, prop)
   }

 return Object.create(Object.prototype, dscrpts) 
}

if (!Object.isExtensible(Object.prototype)) // solo lectura
  { 
    Object.protoype = Object.assign({}, Object.prototype)  
  }

Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'reverse', {configurable: true, value: reversir_descriptores})

var obj = {
 2015 : [01,02,03],
 2016 : [01,02,03,04],
 2017 : [01,02,03]
}
console.log(obj.reverse())
```

**NOTA:** el código anterior sólo funciona sí y sólo sí la implementación de los objetos es similar al  *struct* en *ANSI C* (los miembros se colocan de menor a mayor dirección de memoria según su declaración) en javascript el análogo sería menor a mayor índice en la tabla de descriptores.

### Pequeño hack

Por alguna razón las propiedades con carácteres puramente númericos sí son ordenados en la tabla de descriptores de menor a mayor según su interpretación númerica, independientemente del orden de declaración. Por otro lado propiedades con carácteres alfanúmericos preservan el orden de declaración en la tabla de descriptores.

```js
function reversir_descriptores(){
     var dscrpts = {}

     var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).reverse()

     for(let prop of props)
       {
        dscrpts[prop] = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, prop)
       }

     return Object.create(Object.prototype, dscrpts) 
    }

    if (!Object.isExtensible(Object.prototype)) // solo lectura
      { 
        Object.protoype = Object.assign({}, Object.prototype)  
      }

    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'reverse', {configurable: true, value: reversir_descriptores})

    var obj = {
     _2015 : [01,02,03],
     _2016 : [01,02,03,04],
     _2017 : [01,02,03]
    }
    console.log(obj.reverse())
```

El anterior código utiliza el prefijo *_* para impedir la interpretación numérica de la propiedad

Comment: Convendría indicar que el último ejemplo no funcionará en IE. El código de la pregunta utiliza ES5.

Comment: Wooow, gracias, aun no puedo votar, pero tu información y ejemplo me ayudo como no tenes idea. !Gracias¡

Comment: @Eddy Lo que sí puedes hacer es pulsar aceptar esta respuesta si te parece tan buena como a mi. Es pulsando la marquita verde que hay bajo el número de los votos. Y cuando llegues a 15 puntos podrás votar. Solo se puede aceptar una respuesta por pregunta pero puedes votar en todas las que quieras.

Comment: No existen los arrays asociativos, todo son objetos con atributos (menos los primitivos)
En FF los atributos los guarda de manera ascendente de menor a mayor no importa como los agreges, en teoría si ejecuto `console.log(obj.reverse().reverse())` los tendría que desplegar de mayor a menor y no lo hace, al menos en mi FF

Comment: @Lato *1.* Un objeto es un [arreglo asociativo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), siendo un arreglo asociativo una interfaz, no un tipo, *2.* La consola tiende a ordenar las propiedades en un orden alfanúmerico independientemente del orden en la tabla de descriptores, puedes utilizar `JSON.stringify(obj)` para mostrar lo mismo que `JSON.stringify(obj.reverse().reverse())`, repito que `obj.reverse` no altera en nada el objeto, sólo la forma de iterarlo.

Comment: @Lato, también es digno mencionar que JSON.stringify tiende a ordenar los elementos independientemente de la tabla de descriptores (creo que es menos probable que la consola), así que lo mejor que puedes hacer es simplemente iterar en un `for..in` , para ver la diferencia.

Comment: solo una pregunta mas, sabes a que se debe este error:    Object prototype is read only, properties should not be added

Comment: @Eddy eso es un problema, tu navegador ha definido congelado el prototipo de *Object* deberás crear una copia y redefinirlo `Object.prototype = Object.assign({}, Object.prototype)`